# About conditional sentences

Tags: questions, conditionals

What would you do if you knew you would get the same amount of money whether you worked more or worked less?

What would you do if you knew you will get the same amount of money whether you work more or work less?

Are both my sentence correct?
Do they have different in meaning?
Thanks for answering me

Answer (score 1):

I would say The former implies a more abstract hypothetical situation whereas the latter implies that you will actually get the same amount, and the only thing to imagine is whether or not you know about it.
IE first asks you to imagine two things: You will get the same money either way, and you know you will get the same money either way
Whereas the second implies that you getting the same money is factual, and only asks you to imagine knowing that. And by asking the question, you would be learning that fact anyway, so it would be an odd question to ask. Hope that makes sense!